# How to make sidebar sticky on page scroll?

Tags: css, sidebar, sticky

How to make sidebar sticky on page scroll?

```
<div class="header">This is header</div>
   <div class="row category-page">
      <div class="category-filter col-2">Filter</div>
      <div class="category-content col-10">ontent</div>
   </div>
<div class="footer">This is footer</div>
```

I tried to do it with the position:sticky, but the result is not the same:
When the page is scrolled, only the content is scrolled. And when you scroll to the end of the content, the sidebar itself is already scrolling.

```
.category-filter {
   position: sticky;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
}
```

The following is needed - when the page is scrolled, both the sidebar and the content should be scrolled. And which element ends first, that one should stick to the visible part of the screen.

Preferably in css, since I don't know how to work with js yet.

I really hope that I explained it clearly =))

Comment: in your css u forget to put . in front of your class, like this .category-filter

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: you have two `<div class="row category-page">` but only one of them is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Sticky position generally works fine in CSS, but it does not in one case: it looks up the node tree (HTML document) and if it sees any `overflow: hidden` in parent elements, it does not work.
See this codepen when it works.
[Example](https://codepen.io/shalaw1889/pen/dymrvRN?editors=1100)

However, the same example does not work with `overflow: hidden`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
// CSS
.container {
  height: 300vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: aqua;
  **overflow: hidden;**
  padding: 20rem;
}
.box {
  height: 20rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: orange;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't have the overflow:hidden property on the parent element.